# PHP Result Data Spilt / Explode with assign value

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and working to get some results but failing to achieve my target. I have text file which contains data like this,

```
APAC|AU|enable|SYD1925|8|20150929|WORKING
APAC|AU|disable|ADL7235|3|20120123|RESIGNED
APAC|NZ|disable|NZ1356|6|20110123|RESIGNED
APAC|NZ|enable|NZ1356|3|20130123|WORKING
```

I am trying to search "AU" && "enable" for this text, line by line and I am a bit successful in it. Here is my Code example;

```
public function scan1()
{
    $file = FCPATH.'uploads/example.txt';
    // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $search1 = "AU"; 
    $search2 = "enable";
    $lines = file($file); 
    foreach($lines as $line) 
    { 
        if(stristr($line,$search1) && stristr($line,$search2))
            echo $line;
    } 
}
```

Now, I am trying to explode/split output data and assign variable / array to save in database but I am failing to do so, can someone please help or give me some direction to achieve this. Thank you

Comment: SHow us the code that yuo have for inserting to the database

Comment: @RiggsFollyYou mean text file right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I first need to assign variable to each section of this line after getting. APAC|AU|enable|SYD1925|8|20150929|WORKING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show us your_table scheme.
If '$db' is a handle of the db connection :

```
foreach($lines as $line) 
{ 
    if(stristr($line,$search1) && stristr($line,$search2))
    {
        $arr = explode("|", $line);
        $query = "INSERT INTO your_table VALUES ('".$arr[0]."', '".$arr[1]."', '".$arr[2]."', '".$arr[3]."', '".$arr[4]."', '".$arr[5]."')";
        $db->query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was confused that how all values will go to Database.

Answer (score 0):

First, obtain the file contents with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$str = file_get_contents(FCPATH.'uploads/example.txt');
```

Then, use the regex ([preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all)) to find all portion of text you're looking for:

```
preg_match_all("/APAC\\|(\w{2}\\|\w+)/", $str, $matches);
```

Then adapt the array so the 'AU' and 'enabled' are separated ([array_map](http://php.net/array_map), [explode](http://php.net/explode)):

```
$matches = array_map(function ($v) { return explode('|', $v); }, $matches[1]);
```

So, `print_r($matches);` returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AU
            [1] => enable
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => AU
            [1] => disable
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => NZ
            [1] => disable
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => NZ
            [1] => enable
        )

)
```

Finally, the foreach loop:

```
foreach($matches as $k => $kv)
{
    $search1 = $kv[0]; // AU
    $search2 = $kv[1]; // enabled
}
```

Comment: what if, I found more than 1 results?

Comment: Secondly, I need to reuse each section of "|" in retun results.  APAC|AU|enable|SYD1925|8|20150929|WORKING

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected:

```php
public function scan1()
{
    $file = FCPATH.'uploads/example.txt';
    // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $search1 = "AU"; 
    $search2 = "enable";
    $lines = file($file); 
    foreach($lines as $line) 
    { 
        if(strpos($line,$search1) !== false && strpos($line,$search2) !== false)
            echo $line;
    } 
}
```

using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function for detection.

Comment: Hi , its find the position of the first occurrence only. I need to match two keywords.

Comment: Hi, i used it to match two keywords `strpos($line,$search1) !== false && strpos($line,$search2) !== false`. what do you mean?